# Should the database.yml be configured when testing locally for Heroku with foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Can someone explain to me what they do when they initialise a rails app locally with foreman (part of [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)) (using postgreSQL), destined to run on Heroku?

I'm going by this guide: [developing locally with foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman) and what I don't understand is if we are expected to specify database username and passwords or if foreman is supposed to handle it as Heroku itself does?

This perplexes me a little as if we are supposed to modify the `database.yml` to hook it up to postgreSQL, then what is the point of using foreman instead of `rails server`?

If it does handle it, how does it handle it, and how would I configure my `pg_hba.conf` to respect it? Something like `local all myuser trust`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `database.yml` needs to be configured with valid information for your development and test databases.

Foreman is only running what's in your `Procfile`, not ripping things out and plugging different things in like Heroku does.

So why do you want to use Foreman instead of `rails server`? Because it:

- Runs all roles defined in your `Procfile` with one command
- Automatically loads your `.env`
- Will fail if any of your roles fail (so less scratching your head because some necessary backend service isn't running)